# pandas create new columns from tuple values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
    RMSE    SELECTED DATA   information
0   100 [12, 15, 19, 13]    (arr1, str1, fl1)
1   200 [7, 12, 3]          (arr2, str2, fl2)
2   300 [5, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3]  (arr3, str3, fl3)
```

Here, I want to break up the `information` column into three distinct columns: the first column containing the arrays , the second column containing the string  and the last column containing the float  Thus the new dataframe would look like

```
    RMSE    SELECTED DATA   ARRAYS  STRING  FLOAT
0   100 [12, 15, 19, 13]    arr1    str1    fl1
1   200 [7, 12, 3]          arr2    str2    fl2
2   300 [5, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3]  arr3    str3    fl3
```

I thought one way would be to isolate the `information` column and then slice it using `.apply` like so:

```
df['arrays'] = df['information'].apply(lambda row : row[0])
```

and do this for each entry. But I was curious if there is a better way to do this as if there are many more entries it may become tedious or slow with a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recreate the dataframe

```
tojoin = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('information').to_numpy().tolist(), 
                      index = df.index, 
                      columns = ['ARRAYS', 'STRING', 'FLOAT'])
df = df.join(tojoin)
```

Comment: Nice! I've just tried and it works for me without the ".to_numpy()". Is there any reason you have called it? @BENY

Comment: @Drakax without to_numpy it will work for series, but not for dataframe , for example you can not do df.tolist(), so based on my 2 cents, I just add to_numpy for all the code  in case